# get positions form a Button in a List

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

i want to make a dynamic list with buttons on it. My button in XML looks like this:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/list_with_button_button"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:onClick="extraClick"
            android:text="Extra" />
```

and in my programm i use this

```
public void extraClick(View v){
        v.getPosition?
    }
```

i create the list with this

```
String[] from = new String[]{"name","price","description"};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.price, R.id.description};
        SimpleAdapter layoutAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, currentValues, R.layout.bestellbuttonlist, from, to);
```

how can i get the position from the liste where the button is clicked when i only got the View v?

Thank you

Comment: are you using a listview? or how are you achieving this. could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inflating the button into your ListView in you `getView()` method,

You can `setTag` to that Button like,

```
button.setTag(position);
```

and in `onClick` event, you can get that tag like,

```
int pos = (int) view.getTag();
```

Here is one [EXAMPLE LINK](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) for the same.

Comment: i edit my question, is it possible to setTag with this code? If not, did you know some changes for me?

Comment: nope, you will have to write your custom adapter class..searching on net will give you many example for that...even StackOverflow has many good answers for this too.

Comment: i cant find a solution with this way, did you maybe got a link for me?

Comment: @Boe-Dev see this link here they have used it, [Example Link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive)